# In Angular 8 for Safari, while routing to a new component, layout created by previous route is not getting cleared up & new route is not loading

Tags: javascript, angular8, angular-router

It's happening only in Safari and working fine on Chrome, IE & Firefox. This is how we are routing:

```
this.router.navigate([`${Endpoints}`], { queryParams: {key: null}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'});
```

The constructor of the new route is getting called but ngOnInit() is getting failed, when we click on the screen which shows the previously route painted, then ngOnInit()of the new route gets loaded and new layout gets painted.

We're using the following version of router:

```
"@angular/router": "8.2.8"
```